# InvalidOperationException in editing role

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I get this problem whenever I save the changes I made when changing the roles of a user:

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional
>   information: The ViewData item that has the key 'URole' is of type
>   'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'"

These are the codes of my

```
    GET and POST Edit ` //
    // GET: /AccountAdmin/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        Account account = db.Accounts.Find(id);
        if (account == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        RoleDropDownList(account.URole);
        return View(account);
    }

    //
    // POST: /AccountAdmin/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Account account)
    {
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            RoleDropDownList(account.URole);
            return View(account);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return View(account);
        }
    }`
```

And this is the Edit View

```
    @model MvcApplication3.Models.Account
@ViewBag.Title = "Edit";

    <h2>Edit</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Pword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pword)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.URole, "Role")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("URole", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.URole)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

        @section Scripts{
            <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jqueryval")"></script>
        }
```

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message is quite clear! also post the method for "RoleDropDownList"

Comment: @Ahmedilyas `private void RoleDropDownList(object selectedRole = null)
        {
            var q = from a in db.Roles
                    orderby a.RoleID
                    select a;
            ViewBag.URole = new SelectList(q, "RoleID", "UserRole", selectedRole);
        }`

Comment: Hope giving error for this line  @Html.DropDownList("URole", String.Empty)
Please check again. It should be @Html.DropDownList(model => model.URole, "Role")

Comment: should it be @Html.DropDownList(model => model.URole, "Role")?

Comment: @Amit  It now gives me the error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type